# How can I get the total invocation times on a lambda during a time period

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I am looking for a way to get the total number of invocations on my lambda during a time period. I can find below view from cloudwatch metrics but it shows invocation per units. How can I get the total number of calls during the selected time window?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I have done in the past to find the total in a time period:

- Go to CloudWatch metrics and add a SUM metric to the graph. This should result in something similar to what you have shown
- Select your time range
- Click on the Graphed Metric tab and select the Dynamic labels menu. Select "SUM - sum of all datapoints"
- Now, when you hover over any datapoint, it should show the total from the time period

This is what mine looks like:

[image: Screenshot of AWS]